# "Upload" file from disk in Django

Tags: python, django, file-upload, django-models

I generate a file in python, and want to "upload" that file to the django database. This way it is automatically put inside the media folder, and organized neatly with all other files of my application.

Now here is what I tried: *(type hinting used, since it's python 3.6)*

```
# forms.py
class UploadForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UploadedFile
        fields = ('document',)

# models.py
class UploadedFile(models.Model):
    document = models.FileField(upload_to=get_upload_path)

    # mimetype is generated by filename on save
    mimetype = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    # ... additional fields like temporary

def get_upload_path(instance: UploadedFile, filename):
    if instance.temporary:
        return "uploaded_files/temp/" + filename
    return "uploaded_files/" + filename

# views.py, file_out has been generated
with open(file_out, 'rb') as local_file:
    from django.core.files import File
    form = UploadForm(dict(), {'document': File(local_file)})
    print(form.errors)
    if form.is_valid():
        file = form.save(commit=False)
        # ... set additional fields
        file.save()
        form.save_m2m()
        return file
```

Now this is not the only thing I've tried. First I've gone with setting the `FileField` directly, but that resulted in the `save()` to fail, while the mimetype field is set. Because the original file sits outside the media folder, and thus a suspicious file action is triggered.

Also, the form gives some feedback about the "upload", through the `form.errors`.

Depending on my approach, either the `save()` fails as mentioned above -- meaning the "uploading" does not actually copy the file in the media folder -- or the form returns the error that no file was transmitted, and tells to check the form protocol.

Now my theory is, that I would have to go and initialize my own instance of `InMemoryUploadedFile`, but I could not figure out how to do that myself, and no documentation was available on the internet.

It feels like I'm taking the wrong approach from the get go. How would one do this properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, thanks to [Franey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46247035/2585092) for pointing me at [storage documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/files/#file-storage) which lead me to [contentfile documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/_modules/django/core/files/base/#ContentFile).

The `ContentFile` actually solves the problem, because it basically is the self-instantiated version of `InMemoryUploadedFile` that I was looking for. It's a django `File` that is not stored on disk.

Here's the full solution:

```
# views.py, file_out has been generated
with open(file_out, 'rb') as local_file:
    from django.core.files.base import ContentFile

    # we need to provide a name. Otherwise the Storage.save
    # method reveives a None-parameter and breaks.
    form = UploadForm(dict(), {'document': ContentFile(local_file.read(), name=name)})
    if form.is_valid():
        file = form.save(commit=False)
        # ... set additional fields
        file.save()
        form.save_m2m()
        return file
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have `get_upload_path` defined? If not, that would explain the errors you're getting.

From what I can see you're on the right track. If you don't need a dynamic path for your uploads, if you just want them in `media/uploads`, you can pass in a string value for `upload_to` (from the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to)):

```
# file will be uploaded to MEDIA_ROOT/uploads
document = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads/')
```

Comment: I certainly do. The model works fine when I get the `document` from a regular file upload.

Comment: No idea otherwise? I think I'll add bounty soon

Comment: @nO_OnE_910 Could you include a link to the error message (in a GitHub gist or similar)? It's pretty tough to tell without that.

Comment: Yes, good point. I will add more information now, the link is [here](https://gist.github.com/nO-OnE-910/589f11ce4a1276fcb00a5f086edc9f7b)

Comment: @nO_OnE_910 Why not just create the file directly in your `media/uploads/` directory? If you're generating the file yourself you've got that flexibility, and it should fix the error you're getting.

Comment: Yes, I thought about that. But as said in the original question: _This way it is automatically put inside the media folder, and organized neatly with all other files of my application._ So when I place it in there myself, it will not go through the logic of `get_upload_path`. If I ever change that path-logic, I would have to change it in two different locations. I want to avoid that.

Comment: @nO_OnE_910 You could extract the logic in `get_upload_path` to another function, then use that same function to place the file when you create it. That way you still only have to manage the path logic in one place, and you avoid adding in extra steps.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154629/discussion-between-no-one-910-and-franey).